# Data filtering framework

Tags: classification, data, data-cleaning, binary-classification, active-learning

I have procurement data that needs to be labeled with product categories. It's tabular data, containing 700k rows and a mix of data types (dates, free text, floats, etc.) The product set we currently have isn't exhaustive, so we'll have to create a new one for many of these.

To reduce the problem, I looked for ways to filter out irrelevant rows, for example, because they're not actual products. I've created some filters and was able to filter out about half of the data. This got me wondering whether it would be possible to do this more efficiently in the future. It's essentially a binary classification problem (relevant/irrelevant), but there's no labeled data to start with. I could efficiently create such a set with active learning.

This task seems so common that I suspect there's an application that can already do this, or a framework in (ideally) Python that would make it easy to create it. Does anyone know of such tooling?